# PlayFramework: Integrate Spring Dependency Injection With PlayFramework

Tags: playframework, sbt, java-8

When i try to integrate `Spring-Dependency-Injection` in `PlayFramework` with `Java 8`, I get the following error when compile the code using `play clean compile` command

```
------
value findUserById is not a member of com.harmeetsingh13.controllers.UserController
[error] GET / @com.harmeetsingh13.controllers.UserController.findUserById(userId:Integer)
-------
```

Following is my Configuration and code

```
public class GlobalConfiguration extends GlobalSettings{

private AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();

@Override
public void onStart(Application app) {
    super.onStart(app);

    // AnnotationConfigApplicationContext can only be refreshed once, but we do it here even though this method
    // can be called multiple times. The reason for doing during startup is so that the Play configuration is
    // entirely available to this application context.
    applicationContext.scan("com.harmeetsingh13");
    applicationContext.refresh();

    // This will construct the beans and call any construction lifecycle methods e.g. @PostConstruct
    applicationContext.start();
}

@Override
public void onStop(Application app) {
    // This will call any destruction lifecycle methods and then release the beans e.g. @PreDestroy
    applicationContext.close();

    super.onStop(app);
}

@Override
public <A> A getControllerInstance(Class<A> clazz) throws Exception {
    return applicationContext.getBean(clazz);
}
}
```

My Coltroller:

```
@Named
@Singleton
public class UserController extends Controller{


public static Result findUserById(Integer userId) {
    /*Optional<User> user = userService.findUserById(userId);
    if(user.isPresent()){

    }*/
    return null;
}
}
```

My Route File as follow:

```
Routes

# Home page
GET / @com.harmeetsingh13.controllers.UserController.findUserById(userId:Integer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last i found and answer, When we used Dependency injection with `Play Framework` there no need to declare controller method as a static. Just remove the static keyword from controller method. This is because, the objects are deal in the form of bean, the IOC container create the controller bean and `Play Framework` get the method definition from bean. That's why there is no need to static methods in controller.

```
public Result findUserById(Integer userId) {
 -------
return null;
}
```